# Android : Change App Label programmatically

Tags: java, android, manifest

How can I change application label to change app name shown from java code in android?
I'm refering to:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

in the Android Manifest

Is there any way to update values in **strings.xml** file?

Comment: do you want change title bar????

Comment: Why do you want to change the name programatically? Isnt it always supposed to be fixed.

Comment: @blessenm I also want to change the App Name. Actually, I want to append some values to title bar.

Comment: @hanry Any solution for changing App Name Pragmatically?

Comment: In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android/15249542#15249542) there are interesting answers and they work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not possible by the moment. It is a fixed string in the AndroidManifest.xml file which cannot be changed at runtime.

Comment: Even tho old and not the question i was looking for, this i hope is never allowed as it would allow programs to pose as others or addons

Comment: Actually it *is* possible to change the app title - but not the way the OP was desperately groping at. I like the answer user "Mark" gives below.

Comment: Old thread but it is possible to change app title based on if the locale of the phone is changed?

Comment: @pingOfDoom Yes, just define it as a string resource and provide different values in each localized `strings.xml` file. This probably is already setup for you when you create a new project.

Answer (score 51):

in the activity, i tried

```
this.setTitle("your text");
```

and it worked. I hope it's a common solution

Comment: Yes Mark, It is a common solution and worked with me. Thank you.

Comment: This code is set label of activity, but not label of the app.

Comment: this does not change app name on the launcher, just changes the title of activity

Comment: Works as intended - of course the app name of the launcher can NOT be changed at runtime ;)

Answer (score 12):

Using `<activity-alias>` you can change App icon and name to few predefined by you.

Create such config in `Mannifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name="package.name.MainActivity"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
 android:launchMode="singleTask">
  <intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity-alias android:label="@string/app_name_default" 
 android:icon="@drawable/icon_default" 
 android:name=".MainActivity-Default"
 android:enabled="true"
 android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>   
</activity-alias>

<activity-alias android:label="@string/app_name_flavor_one" 
 android:icon="@drawable/icon_flavor_one" 
 android:name=".MainActivity-Flavor-One"
 android:enabled="false"
 android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>   
</activity-alias>
```

Now you can switch between those two aliases, therefore we will change app icon or/and name.
To switch from Default to Flavor-One use this code.

```
 getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
    new ComponentName("package.name", "package.name.MainActivity-Flavor-One"), 
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
 getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
    new ComponentName("package.name", "package.name.MainActivity-Default"), 
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

**Keep in mind that you have to track that only one alias will be enabled at a time**

Comment: Its taking time to show the another icon in app menu. Refresh time is too long. is there way for sudden change ?/

Comment: Looks like an almost exact copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android/15249542#15249542 Maybe refer to the answer and question instead of copying it.

Answer (score 5):

In Launcher Activity,Before `setContentView()` write this,

```
setTitle("Your Title");
```

I don't know how it's possible, But it's surely works.

Comment: This code is set label of activity, but not label of the app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Its possible, In this question everyone mentioned like

```
this.setTitle("your text");
```

this will change only your activity name not app logo here I show you how to **change the app logo and appname dynamicly**

First add your dynamic app icons in the mipmap folder , after that add the below code in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

**Add `<activity-alias>`  for your app icon**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <!-- Disable the original activity app icon in launcher -->
                <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> -->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity-alias android:label="Anand"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:name=".MainActivityAlias1"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity-alias android:label="Anand 1"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher2"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher2_round"
            android:name=".MainActivityAlias2"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

    </application>
```

After doing these methods on your activity, just do below things on button click

```
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button1.setOnClickListener{
            packageManager?.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    ComponentName(applicationContext.packageName, applicationContext.packageName + ".MainActivityAlias1"),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
            )

            packageManager?.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    ComponentName(applicationContext.packageName, applicationContext.packageName + ".MainActivityAlias2"),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
            )
        }

        button2.setOnClickListener{
            packageManager?.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    ComponentName(applicationContext.packageName, applicationContext.packageName + ".MainActivityAlias1"),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
            )

            packageManager?.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    ComponentName(applicationContext.packageName, applicationContext.packageName + ".MainActivityAlias2"),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
            )
        }
    }
}
```

for more details refer this [github](https://github.com/Katecca/android-dynamic-app-icon.git) project

Answer (score 1):

Application's android:label is a fixed resource referrer.

But the string under this referrer could have multiple values, depending on configuration qualifier names (values-en, -large, -land, etc.), according to
[Providing Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Answer (score 0):

To anyone interested: [Android How to change the application title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975550/android-how-to-change-the-application-title)
But it's not clear if it changes the "application label" (that is, the name of the icon in the application list) or only the window title.

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending the firmware, you can actually accomplish this by changing IconCache.java file and make it show a string with some internal value of the phone.

For example if you want the SIM Toolkit to show the name of the carrier, you can do that this way.

But for regular apps, as it's been said, it's currently not posible.

Answer (score 0):

As Mister Smith said, it is not possible,

but you could use multiple `ActivityAlias`, which can be enabled/disabled dynamically and point to the same targetActivity. Therefore create your chooser for the app name - let the user select one and enable the `ActivityAlias` via the `packageManager`:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, context.getPackageName() + "." + aliasName);
        context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
                                                               PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                                                               PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

To hide the old alias, use the same code with the flag : `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED`

You can also add the possibility to directly add a shortcut to the home launcher, after you enabled the alias. There are plenty ways described here on sow.