# How to have multiple name labels for an Android Application

Tags: android

I am looking to make my Android application have several different names. Ideally, the name would be different after every time the application was opened, chosen from a predefined list.

Can this be done by having multiple values under `<label>` in the Android Manifest?

Another approach I was thinking about is to potentially edit Strings.xml, but as many others have pointed out, this cannot be done at runtime.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this or is it truly impossible? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where exactly are you expecting this different "name labels" to appear? In the action bar? On the launcher icon in the home screen? Somewhere else?

Comment: Launcher icon. Apologies for the ambiguity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android : Change App Label Programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606471/android-change-app-label-programatically)

Comment: Smells like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can have many launcher icons for one application to start your activities, but, if it were possible, changing the name would be confusing to your app's users.

Comment: It is currently Impossible. From the design perspectives why would you want an App with Mutating App names? It will only cause more confusion among the users...

Comment: Its an app game, and the names would have a consistent theme. It's an idea my team had to generate more interest.

Comment: Even if you go with the N launcher icons approach, enabling one at a time based on random-name stuff, it will not work will all home screens. Not all home screens are written that well, and poor ones may not detect the changes in enabled/disabled status until a reboot.