# How to rename APP after install on Android

Tags: android

please help me.

How i can rename app programmatically after install on Android?
For example, i am launch in App with name "TEST", press special button and this APP change name to "test2".

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606471/android-change-app-label-programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, as you cannot change the `android:label` attribute on `<application>` at runtime.

If you are looking to change the launcher icon, you can *try* to do this by having two launcher activities, one initially with `android:enabled="false"`. Then, at runtime, use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to disable your original launcher activity and enable the one that you shipped in a disabled state. However, on some devices, this will require a reboot to take effect, because the home screen might not be paying attention to this sort of state change. And note that this *only* affects the launcher icon, not the app's name shown in Settings or anywhere else in the system that uses the application's label instead of an activity's label.