# Changing the name of an app in manage applications Android menu

Tags: android

I'd like my app to display on that menu with another name and icon, to be clear, I'm refering to the menu that shows all apps installed on the device, in which by tapping the app you can access the options for force stop, uninstall, clear data etc.

It looks like the app displays with the name defined for it on AndroidManifest.xml, with something like:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="mylabel"
```

And that label cannot be changed as shown here: [Android : Change App Label Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606471/android-change-app-label-programatically). In fact, I also agree with a comment of the first answer that says it could give some security problems.

But I'm not 100% sure of that, as maybe the name it takes for displaying there is taking from another source that by default copies the name indicated in AndroidManifest.xml, but that can be changed in its own.

Is there some way to change the name of the application in that android menu?

I think the question is not a duplicate, as I'm asking about changing the name with which it displays on that manage applications menu, although it's true that if that were the only way, then it's duplicated.

Comment: why you need that ?

Comment: Why do you need two separate names for the same app??

Comment: No, you cannot change the application label at runtime.

Comment: I'm developing an app that the user may want to be as hidden as possible to avoid people gossiping its phone and even letting other people to know they have the app. I know it sounds a bit strange, but I promise it isn't anything illegal. Lol.