# Change the App Icon and Name programatically

Tags: xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

I haven´t tried yet. But I would like to know if its possible to allow the user to change the App name and icon on settings of the app, for instance.
For instance, if the user don´t wanna leave his wife know about the app and wish to change name and icon. I ask because I had one app that allow do it and now I need to do this for a client App.

Regards.

Comment: I don't think it is possible using visual studio.

Comment: You should be able to use an activity-alias just like you can with android java https://stackoverflow.com/a/43792801/1341538