# Android: how to update app's label dynamically

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to change the name of the application which is defined in `application` tag like:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Here the *label* is defined in resource xml, but what I want to achieve is that user input ***app_name*** of his choice and save it and then this new name should be used on Home or Launcher screen of device.

I know there is a way to do by using `ActivityAlias` but again the **label** is pre-defined and it's not a dynamic way to do it.

I read some articles that there are some apps like Magisk which changes it's app name & package name through user input.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43792801/9426046) might help you, It's using `ActivityAlias` but there are some pre-defined labels.

Comment: AFAIK, what you are seeking is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices. Note, though, that you could offer dynamic shortcuts that have dynamic labels.

Comment: @danialiranpour thanks! But as I said I know how it works with ActivityAlias but I want dynamic way where user can enter name for the app. ActivityAlias is a sort of hard-coded values defined in xml.