# Notification in Nougat

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have two problem with my app:
1. I don't know how to retrieve the color of the small icon of notification when a notification arrives?
2. Can I edit app name that displayed at top of the notification by programmatically?
 I'm using android Nougat .

[image]

Comment: You cannot change the name of app, but the title of the notification

Comment: But you can try custom notification layout

Comment: tks for your answer. Do you know how to get color of the small icon?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to set smallIcon :(Use Small icon same color as Title Color)

Change color by  [this site](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=0&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=rgb(0%2C%200%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(0%2C%200%2C%200)&crop=0&backgroundShape=none&effects=none&name=ic_launcher)

```
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_icon)
```

[image]

**Reference Code :**

```
 private void sendNotification(String messageBody,String message2, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
           // .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_icon))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_icon)
            .setContentTitle(messageBody)
            .setContentText(message2)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
            .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Tks for answer. But I have to retrieve notification by onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)  method. And I want get the small icon color of the notification that I just retrieved. How I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This API seems to allow custom title and icon: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

Comment: Tks for your answer. But I want custom the app name that displayed at top of the notification. Do you know?

Comment: Only for the notification or for the entire app?

Comment: Only for the notification. Because I need it to display different app name every time my app post notification

Comment: As far as I know, if the notification comes from a push server the operating system will receive the notification first and based on the app ID grab the current app title without the app knowing about the notification. Therefore, in this use case a custom title for notifications seems to be not possible.

If the notification come from the app itsself, the app can set the app title before sending it to the system notification center and display the custom title everytime it sends a new notfiication. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975550/android-how-to-change-the-application-title