# How to change the label(Android)?

Tags: android, label

I had writen a simple Android project. The main Activity has a gallery. Different pictures have differndt Activity. If I click one image, I would go to another Activity. The question is that how can I change the label, if the Activity change through the java code?

Comment: you want to change the label means change the title of the activity?

Comment: Not really sure what are you trying to achieve. So you want to start a new activity when a picture is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to change the title bar, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android) question ...

```
setTitle("My Title Is Better Than Your Title");
```

Comment: or setTitle(R.string.yourresourcename) for better localization of the app ;)