# How to add TitleBar in this android example?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to implement the ListView with section.

I have use [this](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) application to implement the section to my list view.

Now I want to add the Titlebar that display the application page title. Then where do I have to make a change? In the xml file or in the Java file?

Please refer the example and let me tell what should I have to change to make Titlebar for my app.

Comment: Can't find the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
final Activity activity = this;
activity.setTitle("Settings");
```

if you disabled the title bar using, `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`
remove it.

(OR)

Try this..

```
        final Activity activity = this;
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        activity.setTitle("Settings");
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to change title bar for your activity:

1. **Design time** (that is, change title in AndroidManifest.xml file).
2. **By coding** (that is, you can code to change the activity title).

Example for 1st:

you can Change the Title of each screen (i.e. Activity) by setting their **`Android:label`** inside the **`AndroidManifest.xml`** file:

```
<activity android:name=".Hello_World"
                  android:label="This is the Hello World Application">
   </activity>
```

And yes, to display customized title bar for your activity, go through this answer: [How to change the text on the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android/3438352#3438352)

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file you have a section for each activity that looks like this

```
    <activity
        android:label="Your Activity"
        android:name=".YourActivity" />
```

where the `android:label` tag defines what the text in the titlebar is.

Answer (score 0):

To add a title bar in Android Studio, follow these steps:

Open your project in Android Studio.
In the Project pane on the left-hand side, navigate to the app > res > values folder.
Right-click the values folder and select New > Values resource file.
In the New Resource File dialog box, name the file styles.xml and click OK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources><style name="AppTheme" 
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dp</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF00BF</item>
</style></resources>
```

Apply the new theme to your activity by adding the following attribute to your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Go to main file and add after onCreate():

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Home Activity");
```