# How to change Android title bar text color programmatically?

Tags: android, android-titlebar

In my app I populate title bar label from each activity but the text color in the activity and text color in title bar is same. How do I change the title bar text color to a different one?

Answer (score 5):

In your onCreate-method add the following:

```
setTitleColor(YOUR PREFERED COLOR);
```

Comment: Yeah, does not work with Action Bar on Android 4.0+. In that case, [check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920277/how-to-change-action-bar-title-color-in-code/10592561#10592561).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom title bar (then you have to change the color of a simple TextView). Please check this: [How to change the text on the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it from 2 places either in style.xml or proramatically
1.From style.xml : by Modifying TitleTextStyle -setting the `android:textColour` value as desired

2.Or in code    Programatically:

```
int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");  
TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(titleId);
yourTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one

setTitleColor(Color.BLUE);

you can choose different color from Color class.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // Width of TextView
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    ab.setCustomView(tv);
```

For more information check this link :

http://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/09/android-how-to-change-actionbar-title_21.html