# How to change action bar title color in code

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm having trouble changing androids action bar title color programmatically for v11 and up. I can get it done in xml but need to change it dynamically in code. How should I go about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The `ActionBar` title ID is hidden, or in other words, it's internal and accessing it can't be done typically. You can reference it using `Resources.getIdentifier` then `View.findViewById` though.

**Grab the ID for the action_bar_title**

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
```

**Now you can use the ID with a `TextView`**

```
TextView abTitle = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
abTitle.setTextColor(colorId);
```

Comment: This thing doesn't work for me.To make sure, there is no static title in actionbar, so I am using "action_bar_title" within the getIdentifier method call. Same goes for "id" and "android". I am using v7-appcompat library.

Comment: If this is not working for you, make sure you use `setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor))` instead of `setTextColor(R.color.myColor)`. Works smoothly for me on Android 4.0+.

Comment: Any chance you could add how-to adress the subtitle aswell?

Comment: @MathijsSegers Mhmm, just use `action_bar_subtitle` instead.

Comment: @adneal I thought so, maybe add it to the answer. I couldn't find that part googling. Thanks a lot (can't do this by styles since It's customizable by API).

Comment: If "doesn't work" means you get abTitle == null, then check you don't have something like actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE); during action bar initialisation

Comment: Please note that the `setTitle()` method on ActionBar accepts a Spannable as well, as @wily has mentioned in his answer. Much better when some parts of the text needs to be a different colour.

Comment: It does n't work for me..In AppcompatActivity.Can u please suggest anyother way to do this..

Comment: relying on an internal API (action_bar_title id) is a bad idea as it might change without notice

Comment: Answer needs to be updated, update the answer because it looks like this doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 85):

You can use a SpannableString and ForegroundColorSpan to set the colour of the title

```
    Spannable text = new SpannableString(actionBar.getTitle());
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    actionBar.setTitle(text);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, relying on an internal API (action_bar_title id) is a bad idea as it might change without notice.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Specifically on KitKat using v7 appcompat library FAILs on action_bar_title id solution.  Use this answer!

Comment: this is awesome answer, thanks about that, BTW with the same approach you can make Underline on the toolbar title text. But this is for another discussion .

Comment: Works For SupportActionBar Too

Answer (score 35):

Another way is using Html

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle((Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FF4444\">" + getString(R.string.some_string) + "</font>")));
```

Comment: This one is the most bullet proof answer in my opinion.

Comment: This continues to be the most reliable way for me to set it.

Answer (score 16):

If using the [v7 appcompat library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) (tested with r22) then you can call [`setTitleTextColor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setTitleTextColor%28int%29) on the `Toolbar` object that substitutes the action bar for all API levels. For example:

```
Toolbar actionBarToolbar = (Toolbar)activity.findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
if (actionBarToolbar != null)
    actionBarToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: When up upgraded my project to compile for Lollipop, this answer is the only correct one (Adneal's answer crashes)

Comment: I am using support library 21.0.3 and this is not working anymore, if I have not done any error obviously. At first try the IvanP's solution is working.

Comment: @ČikićNenad Fixed for appcompat r22 (at least, should work with r21 too).

Answer (score 9):

If you use [Sherlock Actionbar](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) you may use the sherlock-actionbar-id for supported actionbars (Android below 3.0)

```
int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");    
if ( 0 == titleId ) 
        titleId = com.actionbarsherlock.R.id.abs__action_bar_title;
```

Comment: Cant just do this: getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TITLE"); ??

Comment: Of cause you can do so, when you just want to change the title. but this question was about to change the title-color.

Comment: Therefore you need to get the TextView in the ActionBar and to get there you need the id for the TextView. And the id is different in Sherlock ActionBar and the nativ one.

Answer (score 1):

Using Kotlin and SupportActionBar Use this ->

```
val mSpannableText = SpannableString(supportActionBar?.title)
    mSpannableText.setSpan(
        ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),
        0,
        mSpannableText.length,
        Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
    )
    supportActionBar?.title = mSpannableText
```

Answer (score 0):

For custom color to work, you need to use a `NoActionBar` eg `android:Theme.NoTitleBar` or one of its decendants, then manually add the `Toobar` in your layout, then `setSupportActionBar` in your activity's `onCreate()`,

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Then you can set the title color in toolbar xml `app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"`

See below;

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    
  app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
  app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
  app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
  app:title="@string/app_name" 
  android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material" />
```

Atleast this work form me