# How to change the color of action-bar title?

Tags: android

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setTitle(R.string.title);// set application title
```

I am setting my title through my java code. How to change the color of action-bar title.

```
  <style name="ActionBar.Text.Example" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionBarText</item>
    </style>

  <style name="TitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
            <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">18dip</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920277/how-to-change-action-bar-title-color-in-code

Answer (score 0):

In Android Documentation there is example of actionbar styling: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#AdvancedStyles