# Change the text color of the activity title

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar, xamarin, titlebar

In Xamarin, how can I change the text colour of the text in the `ActionBar`?

I have changed the background colour successfully, but not the text colour.

Here is my code:

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.White);
ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable); 
this.TitleColor = Color.Black;
```

I cannot see a correct method in the `ActionBar` object, and specifying `this.TitleColor` does not work correctly.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920277/how-to-change-action-bar-title-color-in-code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920277/how-to-change-action-bar-title-color-in-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try this?

```
int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
if (actionBarTitleId > 0) {
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
    if (title != null) {
        title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

more info on [this Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color)