# Action Bar's Title Text Size in Android

Tags: android

do any of you know how to get the Text Size in Action Bar's Title

i know we can get ActionBar in android by using this code

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
```

and we can change the Title of that ActionBar by using this code

```
ab.setTitle("This is Title");
```

**Note : I dont want to Change the TextSize in ActionBar's Title , as i can do that by manipulating the XML and using Custom Action Bar. I just want to Know the TextSize of that ActionBar's Title**

I assumed ActionBar use TextView inside it for the Title

and i really want to know if any of you know how to get the TextView from ActionBar's Title

or at least, know how to get the TextView's TextSize from ActionBar's Title

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989310/change-the-text-color-of-the-activity-title/23989404#23989404, with this you can get title as a `TextView` then you can get anything from that,

Answer (score 2):

big thanks for @shayan pourvatan

this is the code that help me

```
int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
if (actionBarTitleId > 0) {
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
    if (title != null) {
        //pretty much i can do anything after i got this TextView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see the `dimens.xml` file of the `appcompat` library where text size is defined for the `ActionBar` title.

```
 <!-- Text size for action bar titles -->
    <dimen name="abc_action_bar_title_text_size">18dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 1):

according to my knowledge,the id of Action Bar Title id hidden,first you have to get id of that Acton Bar Title like:-

```
int ActionBarTitleID = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
```

now use settext on this ID like

```
TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(ActionBarTitleID);   
yourTextView.setTextColor(colorId);
```