# How to change the color of text in the android action bar in Android Lollipop?

Tags: android

No matter what I do, the action bar text is black, I need to change it to white.

I have tried this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

and this

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
TextView abTitle = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
abTitle.setTextColor(colorId);
```

the second answer from here [How to change action bar title color in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920277/how-to-change-action-bar-title-color-in-code), just crashes the program, the first answer doesn't work. Please help??

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `style.xml` inside a new directory called `values-v21` and then simply replace with this:

```
<resources>
    <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <!-- Main theme colors -->
       <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
       <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
       <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
       <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
       <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
       <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
   </style>
```

For more information see [Maintaining Compatibility](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html)

Answer (score 0):

This must work: Add it to res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>

     <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
         <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
     </style>

     <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
         <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Textstyle</item>
     </style>

     <style name="Textstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
         <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
     </style>

</resources>
```

And change your AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">   //  <--------- Here -------->

    <activity
        android:name=".Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
```