# How to change AppCompat v21 toolbar theme programmatically?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

This is my toolbar xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:background="@color/primary_color">



</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I want to change  **app:theme**  programmatically.
How do i do this?

Comment: You can't change the style and theme. What do you want to do? Maybe there is a different solution.

Comment: Well i want to let users to choose color of toolbar.... according to the color i want to change the theme.. so if they choose a dark color theme would be  ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar otherwise it would be light theme

Comment: And link to answer how to set tile color: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26594674/2536878

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this programmatically or with style:

```
Toolbar toolbar; // your toolbar
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(newColor); // i don't tested this method. Write if it's not working
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(titleColor); // if toolbar is white set title to black, if toolbar is black set title to white
```

Or you can do it with style:

Add attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="toolbarStyle" format="reference"/>
</resources>
```

And now change toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
    app:theme="?attr/toolbarStyle"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:background="@color/primary_color">



</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And in styles.xml (if you don't have this create it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyStyle.Dark" parent="AppCompat.Theme">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyStyle.Light" parent="AppCompat.Theme.Light">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

If you select second method (with styles) you must restart activity and use setTheme method before super.onCreate()

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Hi, Krystian. The first one way doesn't work. But maybe you now the way how to change the toolbar between fragments replacing inside one Activity instance ? Need to avoid the Activity recreating. Thanks

Answer (score 25):

Use the following code snippet to add a theme:

```
Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar.getContext().setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark_ActionBar);
```

Comment: Worked For me.. Thanks

Comment: Yes!  This worked!  All the other answers were both way overkill and some didn't work.  The ones I tried didn't work, anyway.  Thank you.

Comment: For me this did more than I wanted.  It set the theme for my entire activity, not just the toolbar.  Be careful if you have other elements in your activity that respond to the theme.

Comment: This is dangerous, it might mess up your activity's theme

Comment: It didn't work for me (for API 30). It will definitely apply the theme to the toolbar's context which is obviously your activity.

Comment: How would I do this if it were a custom toolbar implementation? I want to conditionally switch styles.