# Change toolbar theme programmatically

Tags: android

My code is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/Toolbar_Theme"/>
```

I want to change app:theme in java code.
Can i find any method as `toolbar.setTheme` which used to change style of toolbar?

Comment: You can only change the background color and the title color using code : 
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(newColor); 
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(titleColor);

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225189/how-to-change-appcompat-v21-toolbar-theme-programmatically

Answer (score -11):

You can change it programmatically like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

toolbar.getContext().setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark_ActionBar);
```

Comment: This will chage the parent context theme and can mess with other properties not related with the toolbar.

Comment: Why minuses? It is a right solution, copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42995291/2914140.

Comment: One -1 for copying, just reference the previous solution.

Comment: So many down votes because the solution is not effective for the developers community, so for me, and found as copy paste answer with no reference of the source.

Comment: This change the activity's entire theme, not just for the toolbar