# Action Bar Title Text Color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am having an Activity that extends the AppCompatActivity. I am using the theme **Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar**. Now, the text color of the TitleText in the ActionBar shows up black. I want to set this color to white.

How can this be possibly achieved ?
Do I change the theme to something else (if yes then what) or can I change the color by making changes through the ThemeEditor available in the latest version of the Android Studio or can something be done with the getSupportActionBar() programmatically ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color
follow this link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920277/how-to-change-action-bar-title-color-in-code?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I personally chose the programmatical way.

In your code, you can assign a custom layout to your `ActionBar`.

Like this:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);


ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.topbarclassic,null);
mActionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
```

Then just change the text color of your textview containing the text inside the `ActionBar` as following:

```
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the action bar tittle color using this code
You add below code to your `Oncreate` method

```
setTitleColor(YOUR COLOR);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this way in your `Activity`

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#DCDCDC")));
```