# application name center alignment in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Can I center align the application name in android?

by default the application name is aligned in the left side.

so how to make it aligned center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will try this in xml

```
android:layout_centerhorizontal="true"
```

Comment: Can you say in which XML file i have to use above code. I am also struggling with same problem.

Comment: My application title on title bar is left aligned by default, i want to make it center. Not any textview or other.

Comment: I am posting same thing as new question, i will make it clear there.

Comment: I don't have the option of `centerhorizontal` in `android:layout_` .. how to proceed ?

Comment: Need to know where to apply this attribute.

Answer (score 2):

please set your layout and textview gravity to center if it is not working then try textview layoutGravity to center

Answer (score 1):

you will have to create a custom theme and set the style of window title to suit your needs.
This has some guideline http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/custom-android-window-title/

You could also use FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE and set format accordingly. 
This approach is detailed here.
[How to change the text on the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom title in your *Toolbar* all you need to do is remember is that *Toolbar* is just a *fancy ViewGroup* so you can add a custom title like so:

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This means that you can style the *TextView* however you would like because it's just a regular *TextView*. So in your activity you can access the title like so:

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the theme in *manifests*  its actually explained well in android developer website ... review this link https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up#java

Comment: missing required code example and for which version this potential solution works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        app:titleCentered="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Using ConstraintLayout to align the app name at the centre