# TextView horizontal center in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app screen, i want to show Heading as horizontally center.  I tried with below layout xml codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
  >
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Connections" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767655/application-name-center-alignment-in-android/8767692#8767692

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
  
  >
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Connections" />
</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 163, accepted):

`android:gravity` controls the appearance within the TextView. So if you had two lines of text they would be centered within the bounds of the TextView. Try `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`.

Comment: Notice that this won't work if a RelativeLayout contains an attribute android:gravity="center_horizontal".

Comment: If this doesn't work, make sure that your text view's width is also set to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`

Comment: making the TextView width : wrap content , makes it invisible.

Comment: android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:gravity="center"

I think it's correct. so that TextView will be centered in Layout, and text will be centered in TextView.

Answer (score 20):

Use this:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

within TextView

Answer (score 7):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    >
  <TextView
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Connections" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

use `layout_centerInParent="true"(layout_centerInHorizontal,layout_centerInVertical)`

gravity means the algin of text on textview, not the view itself

Answer (score 4):

replace textview with below code

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="Connections" />
```

Comment: thank you it is working, i think only difference is wrap_content to fill_parent

Answer (score 3):

only add this  `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dip" 
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  >
  <TextView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Connections" />
</RelativeLayout>
```