# change android label name and gravity in androidmanifestfile

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hi i have to developed one sample app.Here i wish to select the app name is Admin Login and gravity is center.here i have to run the app means the app name is diplayed successfully.but the gravity is not worked for me.here i wish to align the app name is center.how can i do.please give me solutions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidlogin.ws"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AndroidLoginExampleActivity"
        android:label="Admin Login"  android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"   android:gravity="center">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

  </manifest>
```

**Edit:**

```
  <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground"> 
    <item name="android:background">#093f7c</item> 
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
 </style> 
 <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme"> 
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: just check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android/3438352#3438352

Comment: A single Google search gave me this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767655/application-name-center-alignment-in-android

Seems to work.

Comment: @Christiaan de Jong:       it is not worked for me yar.so ly asked question

Comment: @user1676640 define own style and check ram kirans comment

Comment: @Ramkiran here i have use below code:<style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#093f7c</item>
          <item name="android:gravity">center</item> 
    </style>
 <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
          <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
    </style>    Here the backgroung color is set successfully.but my gravity is left only.but i wish to ser the gravity is center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your styles. There you specify

```
<item name="android:gravity">center</item>
```

for `CustomWindowTitleBackground`. Its not possible because setting gravity center means it will align in center to its parent. so there is no possibility of giving the layout width to `fill_parent`.

so i think you must use custom xml file and align your title

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom title style/theme. 
Als o check com.example.android.apis.app.CustomTitle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set gravity in AndroidLoginExampleActivity.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
android:id="@+id/layout" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity ="center" >
```

or if you want to use gravity in sub layout then use layout_gravity in sub layout.