# How to modify the activity label?

Tags: android, label

[Activity Label tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl16r.jpg) Hi There. This question might have been answered before but i couldn't find any clear directions. I am new to android and currently learning the basics.

I am trying to change the activity label tag but somehow i couldn't find a way to do so. I have created multi screen app and would like to change each screen label as per the category.  My apologies if my question is not clear.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using a `Toolbar` in your layout to get the actionbar, or are you letting the system provide one for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138007/how-to-change-android-activity-label

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change title of Activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198410/how-to-change-title-of-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest type android :lable ="....." Under the specific activity . 
If you are trying to have label from any text view  in layouts ,then you can think of above answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the title of activities by calling setTitle():

```
setTitle("My Title")
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically,

```
setTitle("myTitle");
```

should work.

In some cases, though, you may need to call

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("myTitle");
```

This may be necessary depending on how you designed your activity.

Answer (score 0):

The title setting mechanism will depend on your layout structure and the kind of AppBar/Toolbar you are using.

If you are using `CoordinatorLayout` with a nested `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, 
the you'll have to call `setTitle()` on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` instance.

If you are using an `AppCompatActivity` you can change the title by calling:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("New Title");
```

If you are using a custom Toolbar element inside your layout, you'll have to set set your title on a Toolbar, then set the Toolbar as Activity's ActionBar like so:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("New toolbar Title");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Note: you'll have to call     `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` AFTER you set the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in your activity onCreate:

```
setTitle("Your Title");
```

Or do it in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="Your Title" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```