# Customized Title bar in android

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I want to develop a title bar in android like this

1. Home Button - Left aligned
2. Application Title - At the center
3. Image Icon - Right Aligned

I am not sure how to do it.
I am a new user and hence not allowed to post the image here. Sorry for inconvinience.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change title bar text in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

To create a custom title bar, you need to do four things

1. Set up a relative layout specifying `TextView` for left, center text, and a `ImageView` aligned in the centre.
2. From the `onCreate` of the activity where the custom title is displayed, call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);`
3. Call `setContentView` as usual.
4. Then you need to instruct that the layout of the custom title is to be put in place with the associated relative layout `getWindow.setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOMER_TITLE, R.layout.my_custom_title);`

From there onwards, its a matter of obtaining the `TextView` and `ImageView` widgets via `findViewById` and calling the appropriate methods of the widget to suit the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way for the change the title bar

1) Normal way,

you can Change the Title of each screen (i.e. Activity) by setting their Android:label

```
<activity android:name=".Hello_World"
     android:label="This is the Hello World Application">
```

2) if you want to Customize title-bar, i.e. you Want to put Image icon and custom-text, then following this
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3438352/1263679)