# How to create custom window title on preference activity android?

Tags: android, icons, title, preferenceactivity, preference

When building an application, sometimes we need to create a custom window title to suit  our needs and make our application differs from  others. I've problem on create icon window title on preference activity by this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.setting);
        setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.setting);
    }
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: See [Customized Title Bar in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713632/customized-title-bar-in-android/11713708#11713708) for this identical question that was asked previously.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {  
protected ImageView img;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);        
    setContentView(R.layout.main_tab);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.img);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar);
    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sc01);
    int width=30;
    int height=20;
    Bitmap resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);
    this.img.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

  }
}
///////In title_bar.xml///////

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="3dp">
    </ImageView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.drawable.icon);
```

Comment: What the difference with my code? That not work, my app force close.

Comment: I used a `.` instead of a `/` between `R.drawable.icon`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you have a solution for my problem? Please review my code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

1. Create custom layout for window title in “layout” folder.

> window_title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:background="#323331">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:src="@drawable/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

1. Create custom style in “values” folder.

> custom_style.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#323331</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

1. Apply custom style in manifest file as theme.

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

4.Apply custom window title in main activity class

> CustomWindowTitle

```
    public class CustomWindowTitle extends PreferenceActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,  R.layout.Your_Custom_Title);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.YourPrf);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That not work for my app, I implement for preference activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can change icon and title of your preference activity in your Manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name="PATH TO YOUR ACTIVITY"
        android:label="@string/title_from_resources" 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_from_resources" >
    </activity>
```