# Scrolling Activity Title

Tags: android, android-activity, title

I load the title in an Activity dynamically; whenever the title is too long, I would like it to scroll so the whole title can be read.

I've tried in a custom XML file and requestFeature,

```
android:singleLine="true" 
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

The other method I've tried

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.title);
textView.setSelected(true); 
textView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
textView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(1);

textView.setFocusable(true);
textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
textView.requestFocus();
textView.setSingleLine(true);
```

gave me nullpointers at ellipsize(). I'm at a loss, really. How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach won't work because`(TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.title)` returns null.

I suggest follow Bhuro's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android), particularly on how to customize the title bar. Essentially, you would need a custom titlebar.xml that defines what you want in your custom title bar (in your case, just a TextView). An titlebar.xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTitle" 
        android:text="This is my new title and it is very very long"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you specify it in your Activity:

```
final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

if (customTitleSupported) {
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);
}
```