# How do I change the android actionbar title and icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I'm trying to do some things on the ActionBar in Android.

I've already added new items in the right side of the action bar.

How can I change the left side of the action bar? I want to change the icon and the text, and I want to add a "Back Button" in the action bar for the other screens

[image: Android Action Bar]

Answer (score 551, accepted):

This is very simple to accomplish

If you want to change it in code, call:

```
setTitle("My new title");
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

And set the values to whatever you please.

Or, in the Android manifest XML file:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
       android:icon="@drawable/my_icon" 
       android:label="My new title" />
```

To enable the back button in your app use:

```
 getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

The code should all be placed in your `onCreate` so that the label/icon changing is transparent to the user, but in reality it can be called anywhere during the activity's lifecycle.

Comment: If you are using the support library to add the actionbar, use `getSupportActionBar` instead of `getActionBar`.

Comment: `getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true)` uses API level 14 or up, if you just want back button functionality in older as well as newer APIs you just need `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled( true ); before setTitle("123");

Comment: If you use the code getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon); can you make it clickable?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Thank you, that's what was missing for me. In Kotlin: `supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)` then `supportActionBar?.title = "your title"`. And it has to be done in `onResume`, not in `onCreate`, when creating the activity with `startActivity`.

Comment: setTitle(...)???? That's it?????!!!??? WOW. IF ONLY android made it this easy for a million other seemingly simple tasks like, for example, hiding the keyboard...

Comment: Setting the title works fine, but setting the icon doesn't work. `getActionBar()` is null and `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(...)` does nothing.

Answer (score 19):

To make a single icon be usable by all your action bars you can do this in your Android Manifest.

```
<application
    android:logo="@drawable/Image">

    ...

</application>
```

Comment: thanks- I wanted a different icon for outside the app (as seen in "All apps") and another icon at the left of the action bar. And this worked. Manifest file still has android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

Comment: This is the right way as it `pre-loads` the icon, programmatically settings icon is slow!

Answer (score 13):

You just need to add these 3 lines of code. Replace the icon with your own icon. If you want to generate icons use [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html)

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_back_arrow);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 12):

In Android 5.0 material design guidelines discourage the use of icon in actionBar

to enable it add the following code

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

credit goes to author of this [article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Defining-The-ActionBar)

Answer (score 10):

If you want to change the Action bar title just give the following 1 line code in the onCreate() of your Activity

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Test");
```

Comment: How can I animate this title change?

Answer (score 8):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.titolo));
actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can change the icon in your by adding whatever icon you want to your respective drawable folders, then changing this line in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

to match whatever the name of your icon is in there.  Or put your icon as ic_launcher, if they're the same icon.  As for what it says, add or change whatever strings match up to that in your res/values/strings.xml file.  Then, once again in your AndroidManifest.xml file, change this line:

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

to whatever the string you have in their.  You'll have to do this for the application as a whole, and whichever activities you want, but the lines are the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What size (dp) should this  `android:icon` in activity tag be?

Answer (score 5):

For that, you can do it in 2 ways: XML or Java. See here: [How to change the text on the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android)

So:

XML:

```
<activity android:name=".Hello_World"
              android:label="This is the Hello World Application">
</activity>
```

Java:

```
public class TitleBar extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

       setContentView(R.layout.main);


       if ( customTitleSupported ) {
           getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);
           }

       final TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
       if ( myTitleText != null ) {
           myTitleText.setText("NEW TITLE");

           // user can also set color using "Color" and then "Color value constant"
          // myTitleText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
       }
 }
}
```

Comment: To do it from code, you should call `setTitle(CharSequence text)` or `setTitle(int titleRes)`. Don't use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE)` unless you are planning to replace the entire title bar with your own custom View.

Answer (score 3):

**For set Title** :

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Title");
```

**For set Icon** :

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.YOUR_ICON_NAME);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the below code inside an onCreate function in your activity.

```
setTitle("NewName");
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the following call inside `onNavigationItemSelected`:

```
HomeActivity.this.setTitle(item.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 2):

This work for me:

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.baseline_dehaze_white_24);
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to manifest in which specific activity you want to change Action bar Title name and write 
 android:label="Title name"

Answer (score 0):

The action bar title will, by default, use the label of the current activity, but you can also set it programmatically via `ActionBar.setTitle()`.

To implement the "Back" (more precisely, "Up") button functionality you're talking about, read the "Using the App Icon for Navigation" section of the [Action Bar developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home).

Finally, to change the icon, the guide covers that as well. In short, the action bar will display the image supplied in `android:icon` in your manifest's `application` or `activity` element, if there is one. The typical practice is to create an application icon (in all of the various densities you'll need) named `ic_launcher.png`, and place it in your `drawable-*` directories.

Answer (score 0):

I got `non-static method setTitle(CharSequence) cannot be referenced from a static context` error because I used `setTitle()` in static PlaceholderFragment class. I solved it by using `getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("new title");`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do as follow :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        setTitle("Activity 2")
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to **AndroidManifest.xml** file.
Find the `<application>` tag 
There you can see a attribute

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Now go to **res > values > strings.xml**

Change the

```
<string name="app_name">MainActivity</string>
```

to

```
<string name="app_name">Your Desired Name</string>
```

Example

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SubmitForm">

        </activity>
    </application>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Your Desired Name</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: it change the whole add name