# No App Icon on ActionBar

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-actionbar

There are a lot of queries here about adding icons to ActionBar but none solved my problem. If you know a duplicate of this question, feel free to comment or close this question.

I migrated my project to IntelliJ and I didn't encounter this problem with my previous IDE (Eclipse).

**PROBLEM: The app icon is not displayed in the ActionBar.**

[image]

I think it's supposed to be added by default that's why I can't add it through its XML

[image]

Here's its XML

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Refer to this Answer which is explained in very detailed:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14483595/4750017

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As of AppCompat version 21, the Action Bar follows the [material design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) and uses a [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html):

> - *A title and subtitle.* The title should be a signpost for the Toolbar's current position in the navigation hierarchy and the content contained there. The subtitle, if present should indicate any extended information about the current content. **If an app uses a logo image it should strongly consider omitting a title and subtitle.**
>
> In modern Android UIs developers should lean more on a visually distinct color scheme for toolbars than on their application icon. **The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.**

However, if you want an application icon, [setLogo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#setLogo(int)) is the correct method.

Comment: Great answer! This is how answers are supposed to be written imho.

Answer (score 28):

Update your `onCreate()` method with the code below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

**NOTE:** `ic_launcher` is the icon you want to display in your actionbar. To display it, add the icon in the drawable folder of your app project.

Comment: Worked for me as well. :) Awesome. simplest solution. copy & paste 3 lines of code & you're done.

Comment: worked like magic. awesome!

Answer (score 10):

In your `Style.xml` file:

```
 <style name="MyTheme_ActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="icon">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>
  </style>
```

In `activity` add this code:

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```

Comment: I added "ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE" to get the title as well.

Comment: This is the best solution since the image doesn't need to be specified in every activity.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the Material theme and are fine having an Activity that looks more JellyBean/Kitkat style and includes the icon in the Action Bar, you can do the following:

First, change themes setting in styles.xml from this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

To this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Now change all your Activities to inherit from android.app.Activity instead of android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.  That is:

Change this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
```

To this:

```
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

The end of result of doing both of the above steps is that the icon as specified by the android:icon attribute in AndroidManifest.xml will appear in the Action Bar.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. Your `onCreate` method should have these lines:

```
ActionBar menu = getSupportActionBar();
menu.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
menu.setIcon(R.mipmap.imageFile);
```

Make sure the `imageFile` is a .png in the `mipmap` folder. To get the icon exactly at the start of your action bar, the `mipmap` folder should have multiple versions of the image file in all screen sizes: hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi, etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Setting Icon On the Action Bar

***Showing Icon On the Action Bar Can Be Tricky***

If you are extending `Activity` this should be enough:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

If you are extending `AppCompatActivity` then additional code is needed:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```