# v7-21 ActionBarActivity not showing the app main icon on the left

Tags: android-activity, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I implemented a basic activity as

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

and when I add an actionbar with the menu as below, the app icon defined in the AndroidManifest.xml shows up nicely

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/logo_green"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
```

When I try to change to android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity ( and switch to compatible AppCompat theme like @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) the main app menu in the action bar strangely disappears

I tried getting it back to where it should be in the Oncreate() method but it does not work

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.green_drawable);
```

#### action bar xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Search / will display always -->


    <item android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:icon="@drawable/notification_active"
        android:title="Setup"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/add_friends"
        android:title="Add Friends"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>


    <item android:id="@+id/action_setup"
        android:icon="@drawable/trackingicon"
        android:title="Setup"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_help"
        android:icon="@drawable/helpicon"
        android:title="Contact Support"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>


</menu>
```

Answer (score 25):

`setIcon/setLogo` method will only work if you have set **DisplayOptions** Try this -

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

You can also set options for displaying LOGO(just add constant `ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO`). More information - [displayOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayOptions(int,%20int))

Comment: I've been forever searching for this answer!  Thank you.

Comment: @Vintesh but it leaves blank space to left of icon. How to remove this space? Thanks!

Comment: If i am understanding correct then, you should try [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354812/android-remove-left-margin-from-actionbars-custom-layout) or [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026007/remove-padding-around-action-bar-left-icon-on-android-4-0) or creating custom toolbar will surely work.