# Can't see icon on my action bar (Android)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am new to android and currently trying to follow [Android developer training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html) and learn the use of action bar. For some reason can't see any icon on my action bar.

Here are steps I did (saw also [previous stackoverflow threads about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483393/how-do-i-change-the-android-actionbar-title-and-icon)):

**Step 1:** Just followed the training instrucations. According to it, all you need is to set the min sdk to the menifest element and also set a Theme and here is what I did. In adition I installed *Android Support Repository* (ver 11) to support the theme.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.guy.guaranteemanager" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    ...
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Result: in my emulator I see the title but don't see an icon.

**Step 2:** 
I tried to implicitely set the icon in the activity xml element

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="Main Page 1">
```

Result: See the updated title but no icon.

**Step 3:**
I tried to change it from the code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
setTitle("My new title");
```

Result: See the updated title but no icon.

**Step 4:** This question is not a duplication of the linked question, because based on [this linked suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720759/no-app-icon-on-actionbar?lq=1), I tried to replace

```
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

with:

```
actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Result: See the updated title but no icon.

So - What is blocking my icon from being presented. Is it some XML definition? the theme is not right? something else?

My related styles.xml looks like that:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: post your styles.xml file

Comment: add this line actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); before actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);