# Android use font-awesome font as icon in menu item

Tags: android, font-awesome

I'm just learning android so sorry for my lack of knowledge on the subject. I mainly work as a Web Developer and we use Font Awesome all the time so I was trying to get it to work with Android. I first found out I could use font awesome [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15762875/2066736). With some deeper searching I found out how to put a font awesome icon in the action menu bar in the title [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15181195/2066736). I am missing out on having the ability to have backup text when there is room by setting the title instead of the icon and the title.

I was wondering if I could set the icon in font awesome instead of the title and just have normal descriptive text for the title. It wants a drawable or drawable resource id when I do the setIcon method on the menu-item. Could I convert it to a drawable? What is the best way to approach keeping font awesome for the icon and having both the icon and title? Any help or direction is appreciated.

So I have the following code in my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/32780748/2066736
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.redbird_webkit_onwht);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        setFontAwesomeMenuItem(menu, R.string.icon_calendar, R.id.action_calendar);
        setFontAwesomeMenuItem(menu, R.string.icon_search, R.id.action_search);
        setFontAwesomeMenuItem(menu, R.string.icon_plus, R.id.action_new_post);

        // menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT, 102, R.string.logout);

        return true;
    }

    private void setFontAwesomeMenuItem (Menu menu, int rIdString, int rIdIdOfElement) {
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(getString(rIdString));
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "fontawesome-webfont.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        menu.findItem(rIdIdOfElement).setTitle(s);
    }
}
```

And I got the following TypefaceSpan class from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15181195/2066736):

```
/**
 * Style a {@link Spannable} with a custom {@link Typeface}.
 *
 * @author Tristan Waddington
 * copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15181195/2066736
 */
public class TypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {
    /** An <code>LruCache</code> for previously loaded typefaces. */
    private static LruCache<String, Typeface> sTypefaceCache =
            new LruCache<String, Typeface>(12);

    private Typeface mTypeface;

    /**
     * Load the {@link Typeface} and apply to a {@link Spannable}.
     */
    public TypefaceSpan(Context context, String typefaceName) {
        mTypeface = sTypefaceCache.get(typefaceName);

        if (mTypeface == null) {
            mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext()
                    .getAssets(), String.format("fonts/%s", typefaceName));

            // Cache the loaded Typeface
            sTypefaceCache.put(typefaceName, mTypeface);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
        p.setTypeface(mTypeface);

        // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
        p.setFlags(p.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);

        // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
        tp.setFlags(tp.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer is late but for future visitors there is a great library for working with font awesome in android called iconify written by [JoanZapata](https://github.com/JoanZapata). You can find it [here](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify)

After library being corectly initialized you can do something like this with your ActionBar menu item:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

   <item
       android:id="@+id/item_menu
       showAsAction="always"
       android:title="@string/title"/>

</menu>
```

and from java code you only need to do something like this:

```
 menu.findItem(R.id.item_menu).setIcon(
    new IconDrawable(this, FontAwesomeIcons.fa_share)
    .colorRes(R.color.ab_icon)
    .actionBarSize());
```

Hope this would help someone :) Ask, if you have any questions:)

Comment: I am getting this error: Unable to find the module associated with icon fa-barcode, have you registered the module you are trying to use with Iconify.with(...) in your Application?  How can I solve this?  Do I need to add anything other than     compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.2.2' line in the build.gradle?

Comment: @Vincy Yes. You need to init the library `Iconify.with(new FontAwesomeModule())...` as shown in documentation, just below the `public class MyApplication extends Application {...` block. Create class extending Aplication  Here is example how to extend the Application class https://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/ . The important thing is to register it in manifest: `android:name="YourApplicationClassName"` inside <application> tag

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Karol Zyglowicz.  It worked like a charm!  I missed the Iconify.with(new FontAwesomeModule())... part and the moment I added it, I was in the moon! LOL!  Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Now, I need it in while color and this is what I have done in my code but it draws as black...     menu.findItem(R.id.menuBarcodeScanner).setIcon(new IconDrawable(this, FontAwesomeIcons.fa_barcode)
                .colorRes(R.color.white)
                .actionBarSize()
                .color(R.color.white)
                );
What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: have you declared your `<color name="white">#ffffff</color>` in your `colors.xml`?  This should work because the icon is showing, so it's probably your's code related bug. Maybe you overwrote this in `styles.xml` or something... I'm not able to find mistake remotly :(

Comment: Yes, but did not take it but I had to change my code like this and then it worked but very strange though...                                                                         IconDrawable iconDrawable = new IconDrawable(this, FontAwesomeIcons.fa_barcode)
      .actionBarSize();
    iconDrawable.color(Color.WHITE);
    iconDrawable.colorRes(R.color.white);

    menu.findItem(R.id.menuBarcodeScanner).setIcon(iconDrawable);

Comment: Iconify is no longer maintained

Answer (score 5):

Please check this:

```
TextDrawable faIcon = new TextDrawable(this);
faIcon.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
faIcon.setTextAlign(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
faIcon.setTypeface(FontAwesomeManager.getTypeface(this, FontAwesomeManager.FONTAWESOME));
faIcon.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.fa_android));
Menu menu = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.menu);
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item);
menuItem.setIcon(faIcon);
```

You can get TextDrawable class from [here](https://github.com/devunwired/textdrawable/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/example/textdrawable/drawable/TextDrawable.java)

[Source](http://blog.incognitech.in/font-awesome-in-android/)

Comment: This is great, cause no need to import other libs + works not only for Fontawesome, but also for my custom made fonts, like mine custom made icomoon fonts.