# Icon doesn't show on app android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with my app.
I know there are similar questions, but they didn't help me.
My app icon is not visible.
I added a new icon via `mipmap -> NEW -> Image Asset`.
But it doesn't show.

**Here is my Manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.owner.takeandgo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/my_car"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/round_car"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".controller.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".controller.AddCarActivity"
            android:label="Add_Car" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controller.AddClientActivity"
            android:label="Add Client" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controller.AddCarModelActivity"
            android:label="Add Car Model" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controller.ShowCarListActivity"
            android:label="Show Car List" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controller.ShowCarModelListActivity"
            android:label="Show Car Model List" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controller.ShowBranchListActivity"
            android:label="Show Branch List" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controller.ShowClientListActivity"
            android:label="Show Client List" />
        <activity
            android:name=".controller.AddBranchActivity"
            android:label="Add Branch"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**And this is the style I use:**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**This is my XML layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.owner.takeandgo.controller.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AddCarButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Car" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AddBranchButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Branch" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AddCarModelButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Car Model" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AddClientButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Client" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/showCarListButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Show Car List" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/showBranchListButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Branch List" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/showCarModelListButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Car Model List" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/showClientListButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Client List" />


   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And this is a picture of the `Android Emulator`, Only the text appears but not the icon:

[image: This is how it looks:]

Comment: Where icon is not showing ?

Comment: I added a picture so you can see

Comment: Where are you are using icon ?

Comment: What do you mean? you can see in the manifest file

Comment: add your code where you are setting your icon

Comment: @Elizabeth XML layout is required, and manifest is not.

Comment: In your layout, you don't have to use the icon that will show on the emulator. By setting the app icon to manifest file the icon will show on your device. Please check on your device or emulator app have the icon? If in your device app shows the icon then it works fine.

Comment: That what I did' but the app doesn't have the ion

Comment: There wont be icon in action bar when you change app icon in manifest. Check your launcher and see that icon has changed there.

Comment: If you want to set logo in action bar read this answer first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26720920/3305365

Comment: I allready read it. But nothing there worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It works now.
I added these lines to th main activity:

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.my_car);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```