# Passing URL and a title to a WebView

Tags: android

I have a list view with items `[google, yahoo, bing ...]`. By clicking on each item a webview must be loaded with the corresponding URL. My problem is that I have created a list view with items in it but I need only one class for loading all the URLs. So when I click on *google* the webview must load the google website and if I press yahoo it must load the *yahoo* website in the same webview.

I want to pass the URL of the clicked item to the next page (webview).

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    populateListView();
    clickEvent();

}

private void populateListView() {
    String[] str={"Google","yahoo", "bing"};
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.textview,str);
    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewone);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


}
private void clickEvent() {
    final ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewone);   

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
             view.setSelected(true); 
            switch( position )
            {
               case 0:   Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Mywebpage.class);     
                         startActivity(newActivity0);   
                         break;

            }              
        }

    });
}
```

**Mywebpage.java**

```
public class Mywebpage extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webviewpage);
        WebView wbView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        wbView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        wbView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick an dirty solution would be to parse the text of the clicked item and do an if else cascade like 
Sting url;
if(text.equals("Google") {
  url="http://www.google.com";
} else if (text.equals("Yahoo") { 
  url="http://www.yahoo.com";
} else if ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send **title** and **url** to webview class pass intent extra to webview class,i.e. Rewrite your switch case as

```
Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Mywebpage.class);
newActivity0.putExtra("title", str[position]);
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        newActivity0.putExtra("url", "http://www.google.com");
        break;
    case 1:
        newActivity0.putExtra("url", "http://www.yahoo.com");
        break;
    case 2:
        newActivity0.putExtra("url", "http://www.bing.com");
        break;
}

startActivity(newActivity0);
```

and define

```
 String[] str={"Google","yahoo", "bing"};
```

as class variable instead of `populateListView` method.

and in your `Mywebpage` class get intent as

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webviewpage);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String title, url;

    if (extras != null) {
        title = extras.getString("title");
        url = extras.getString("url");

        WebView wbView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        wbView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wbView.loadUrl(url);
    } //rest code
```

**Edit:**

Make sure you are connected to internet and you have following permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: what is str[position]here??i;m getting error on this?

Comment: @Thusharaprasad did you define str array in your class?see answer.

Comment: yes i define str array in that populate listview method.

Comment: @Thusharaprasad remove str array from that method and add below `public class MainActivity extends Activity {
` line.

Comment: k k nw i undersood that i need to define as my class variable

Comment: is it  wbView.loadUrl(url);

Comment: @Thusharaprasad change `wbView.loadUrl(title);` to `wbView.loadUrl(url);`

Comment: thanks its solved..but i want to change the action bar title of my webview as my tile of list view row.how is it possible?? i try actionbar.settitle("title") ;

Comment: @Thusharaprasad see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483393/how-do-i-change-the-android-actionbar-title-and-icon

Comment: @Thushara,@Giru-bhai can you please check out a similar issue in my thread and post a solution.?

Comment: @Thushara,@Giru-bhai can you please check out a similar issue in my thread and post a solution.?stackoverflow.com/q/28809328/1278860

Answer (score 2):

Create an array 
 `String urlStrArray= {"http://www.google.com","http://www.yahoo.com","http://www.bing.com"};`

and in -

```
    @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                 view.setSelected(true); 
                       Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Mywebpage.class); 
                       intent.putExtra("url",urlStrArray[position]);
                       startActivity(newActivity0);      
            }
```

Comment: try other options.. do they work? if yes then change http to https for google.

Comment: if my answer helped, you can 'accept'/ 'upvote' my answer so that it could help others facing same issue.

Comment: @Darpan, can you please check out similar problem in this thread and provide a solution.? How to load static html files as items in listview.?

Comment: @Mannii88 Did not get what do you mean by loading static htmls as 'items', And ask a new question and share the link with me. Asking new question in comments is not a good practice. :)