# Where do I have to include getActionBar().setIcon()?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to set the icon of the actionBar and make it able to go back by tapping it as [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483393/how-do-i-change-the-android-actionbar-title-and-icon) says, the problem is that the app always get closed when I try to open it. I've tried to include `getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo_cartas);` inside of `onCreate()` and `onCreateOptionsMenu()` methods, but it always fails. I've also included the icon on the manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_cartas"
        android:logo="@drawable/logo_cartas"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

But it still fails, so where do I have to place `getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo_cartas);` or what am I doing wrong?

`onCreate()` method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo_cartas);

}
```

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` method:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_seleccion_tamanio, menu);
    return true;
}
```

logcat output:

```
02-18 14:53:08.202    1957-1957/com.example.nacho.cartas E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.nacho.cartas.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:27)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2490)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:275)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:276)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:79)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.preparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:979)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.doInvalidatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1182)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.access$100(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:79)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:118)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And as I said, the same thing happens when I place it in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` menu

Answer (score 1):

place `getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo_cartas);` in onCreate

remove it from oncreateoptionmenu

Comment: As I said, if I place it in onCreate() method, Android Studio throws me a NullPinterException and the app fails when it treat to open. And the same thing happens when I place it in onCreateOptionsMenu() method.

Comment: check answer again...what is your minimum api ?

Answer (score 0):

The most important line is not the one with the icon. Add this lines in onCreate to be able to go back.

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Don't worry about that. The real problem is that the app fail when I treat to open it.

Comment: Add the logcat output and the Java source code of your onCreate please.

Comment: The logcat says that the app crashes in onCreateOptionsMenu. Please add that code too.

Comment: I didn't add it because I didn't edit anything on that method, but there is ;)

Comment: Are you using AppCompat? Try using `getSupportActionBar()` instead.