# how to add logo with app label in android studio

Tags: android

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/logo"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

This is my androidmanifest.xml

and in mainactivity.java i use this lines to show logo in action bar.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
```

after using this two lines in .java file my logo is showing in the display  but the app label is gone....
is their any method by which logo & app label both will shown in actionbar after compiling apk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the android actionbar title and icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483393/how-do-i-change-the-android-actionbar-title-and-icon)

Comment: Try to put `android:label="@string/app_name` to your `Activity`

Answer (score 2):

You not need the two lines in mainactivity.java, you have to select a Theme with the ActionBar:

From res>layout>activity_main.xml(or whatever is the name of the layout of your activity): in the "Design" tab change the theme in "Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" for example.

Or from the AndroidManifest.xml in your app add (or change):

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

where "AppTheme" is defined in res>values>styles.xml as:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
```

Of course in your manifest you have to define the name and logo in the `<application>` level:

```
<application
  android:logo="@drawable/logo"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your Activity in manifest.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

copy your image file and paste it to the res->minmap folder and then goto your AndroidManifest file and locate the below option

###### android:icon="@mipmap/image_file_name"

give your icon image file name name here (image_file_name) then run your app.