# can i change the android actionbar title to any Gujarati font?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to do some things on the Action Bar in Android

How can I change the Title of the action bar to Gujarati Font.?[image: I want gujarati Title at this point]

Please Specify The Font...

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483393/how-do-i-change-the-android-actionbar-title-and-icon

Comment: it's not duplicate man.. i use same image for specification.. i specify that i want gujarati title in action bar..

Comment: your question same as that question,thats why i think your question as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: is's okay.., i use that image for my question but it is totally different question..i want gujarati title.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to set gujrati fonts using a ttf file

a text view example

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "yourfont.ttf");
    text.setTypeface(font);
```

and for action bar

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id",
            "android");
    TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
    yourTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    yourTextView.setTypeface(face);
```

Comment: what action bar are you trying , try "Holo Theme", and  api >3.0

Answer (score 0):

you can do customization for actionbar
http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

you can add gujarati font the code is [here](http://www.anirdesh.com/Gujarati/add-gujarati-font-in-android.php)