# How can I change the title of a action bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm doing a project in Android Studio using empty activities but in both of them the title still being the same, like in the image:

[image]

How can I change the title of the second activity to 'Form' instead of 'Agenda' as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the android actionbar title and icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483393/how-do-i-change-the-android-actionbar-title-and-icon)

Comment: are you using toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy.
In every .class you want a different title in your actionbar, you only have yo setTitle.
Like here:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle("Your custom title");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using this line of code :

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Form");
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

In you second activity in `OnCreate` method add this line

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Form");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`toolbar.setTitle("title");`

Comment: op didn't use toolbar as actionbar

Answer (score 0):

**Just do this.**

Add this in your Form activity class onCreate method.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setTitle("Form");
```

Answer (score 0):

call

```
setTitle("title")
```

onCreate, or u can set label in *AdnroidManifest.xml* file to activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="custom label string"
    android:theme="theme..." >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```