# How to Change Labels in different Android Screens using AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-3.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXYRv.png)I tried with below code, but the labels of different screens are missing and not visible in User Interface and Can you tell me how to solve this issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.geeth.myprofile">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="My Profile">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProfilePhoto"
                  android:label="My Profile Picture"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

See below Image I am getting output like this,I request you is there any corrections required in above code

Comment: Did you mean the title "My profile" and "My profile picture"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the android actionbar title and icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483393/how-do-i-change-the-android-actionbar-title-and-icon)

Answer (score 1):

did you mean Activity title? then you can use this

```
setTitle("Your Title");
```

or if you use toolbar 
use

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");`
```

or via AndroidManifest

```
android:label="My Activity Title"
```

Comment: It's about Activity Title and Can I know how to change titles for each and every screen by means of AndroidManifest. I have Three Screens as Follows                                                                                                                1)My Profile                                                                                                           2)My Profile Picture                                                                                              3)Education

Comment: then just use android:label="My Activity Title" in manifest of the activity tag of every activity you want .

Comment: I tried , Once see above Code I kept as you told in above code and can you suggest in above code

Comment: please post your activity oncreate code as well, I think there might be some code in your activity which is overriding title from manifest

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to accomplish

If you want to change it in code, call:

> setTitle("My title");  OR
>
> getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");

And set the values to whatever you please.

Or, in the Android manifest XML file:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"  
       android:label="My title" />
```

The code should all be placed in your `onCreate` so that the label/icon changing is transparent to the user, but in reality it can be called anywhere during the activity's lifecycle.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/mgb"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: package com.example.geeth.myprofile

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class ProfilePhoto : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_photo)

    }
}                                @Rahul

Comment: please add above mention method in this function and check

Comment: Actually I am beginner to Android Coding @Rahul

Comment: <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

</resources>                                                                                                  Here is the code for style.xml

Comment: are you able to go from main activity to profile via intent??