# Screen titles are not working in Android studio

Tags: android

I  tried to change default Screen Title in an android manifest file by adding `android:label="Title name"` in each activity.it is not working.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="My Profile">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Work" android:label="Work Experience"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Educaton" android:label="Education"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Profilephoto" android:label="My Profile Photo"></activity>
```

Comment: Prefer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483393/how-do-i-change-the-android-actionbar-title-and-icon

Answer (score 1):

Try setTitle by itself, like this:

```java
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    getActivity().setTitle("My Title");
//...
}
```

Just an FYI, you can optionally do it from the XML.

In the AndroidManifest.xml, you can set it with

```java
android:label="@string/my_activity_label"
```

**Example:**

```
 <activity
    android:name=".FirstActivity"
    android:label="@string/first_activity_title" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```