# Trying to change Android title to look better: requestWindowFeature

Tags: android

Sample code:

```
// activity contains different controls so inherits from Activity
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener, TextWatcher  {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        boolean titleSupported = false;            
        if (true) { // for on/off testing
          titleSupported = this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        } 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android
        if (titleSupported)) {
          getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);
          final TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
          if ( myTitleText != null ) {
            myTitleText.setText("@string/app_name");                    
          }                  
        }
```

When I include the "requestWindowFeature" the app stops/crashes in emulator. I don't understand why. I am new to Eclipse and Android, but from what I can search, I am doing things in the correct order. Any ideas of the cause?

with **"requestWindowFeature"** *before* **"setContentView"** I get:

> 02-04 12:35:05.883: E/AndroidRuntime(755): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.xxx.yyy/com.xxx.yyy.Main}:
>   android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles
>   with other title features

With **"setContentView"** *before* **"requestWindowFeature"** I get:

> 02-04 12:32:32.660: E/AndroidRuntime(784): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.yyy/com.xxx.yyy.Main}:
>   android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called
>   before adding content

Comment: any stacktrace on logcat?

Comment: Added! Sorry I did not add it in my initial question.

Comment: Can you show what is `titleSupported` ?

Comment: I have now included complete example of what I am trying to achieve. (Just in case it in any way is related to my question and/or if others searching for the same can use it some day into the future.)

Answer (score 1):

take the requestfeature call after setcontentview

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    titleSupported = this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

Comment: I do not believe that solves my problem. I have expanded my original post. (I get an error as well using your suggestion.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

`<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>`

in your theme.