# How to set the text color of titlebar?

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I am using this as the theme.

```
<style name="ThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TitleTextColor</item>
</style>

<style name="WindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/waterblue</item>        
</style>

<style name="TitleTextColor">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

With this background image is got assigned but text color is not changing.

In manifest I am using like this.

```
<application
    android:name="com.example"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeSelector">
```

Comment: How you use this style in TextView ?

Comment: try to apply theme for textview....

Comment: Is there any way to get the control of TitleBar TextView or you are telling me to create custom TitleBar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is worked for me.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="ThemeSelector" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar</item>        
</style>

<style name="myTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/lblue</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
    <item name="android:height">@dimen/app_head_height</item>
</style>

<style name="myTheme.ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/app_head</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line in your `style.xml` for API level 23 and above.

```
<item name="android:titleTextColor">@color/black</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<style name="ThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextColor</item>
</style>

<style name="WindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/waterblue</item>        
</style>

<style name="TitleTextColor">
    <item name="android:text">@string/app_name</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#a23421</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I have tried this, it is setting "WindowTitleBackground" but not "TitleTextColor"

Answer (score 0):

I guess the attribute name will be **android:titleTextStyle** instead of **android:textAppearance**

Answer (score 0):

Yas Bro You can do this...

even you made your own custom titlebar ...

Just Go through this link

[How to change the text on the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android)

which is from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet I found online:
It worked perfectly for me.

```
private void createCustomActionBar() {
    this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.title_bar, null);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Lobster-Regular.ttf");
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lblActionBarTitle)).setTypeface(tf);
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lblActionBarTitle)).setTypeface(tf);
    this.getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
    this.getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#212121")));
}
```

Call this method just after your setContentView(R.layout.main_activity) line in your main activity. If you are using a standard activity replace the instances of getSupportActionBar with getActionBar.