# Is it possible to define name of app inside activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to know if its possible to change my app name within my MainActivity.java?  I want the top title bar to have a changing score during different actions throughout the app.

Comment: The top title bar is called the `ActionBar` and you don't have to change the name of the application to change what it says.  For more information, check the [developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
getActionBar().setTitle("My new title");
```

Inside your `Activity`.