# Why can't I change the label in the action bar for each screen in my app?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The action bar for the 2 activities I have don't have a label.  I want the main screen to have the app name and the next screen to have a different label.  Here is my manifest file:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/MSTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.android.recipme.MainScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.recipme.MyRecipes"
            android:label="@string/my_recipes" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

I've searched for some answers and can't seem to get anything right.  Please help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the title of the desired activity, including the following line should be what you want, usually onCreate( ) is where you'd want to put this:

```
setTitle("SetYourTitle Here");
```

You can refer to this thread for more information: [How to change the text on the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android)

Comment: There's no way of doing this in xml?

Comment: When you say "The action bar for the 2 activities I have don't have a label", does that mean the ActionBar (where the title appears) is not showing up?

Comment: Yes that's correct.  It's just blank, but if I put android:label="@string/app_name" under application, it will add the label.  Problem is, it will add the app_name to all screens and I was hoping to have different label for the 2 screens.  Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: You can try removing the line android:theme="@style/MSTheme" and see if that helps. Otherwise I would put android:label="@string/app_name" under application to make the title bar appear and then call setTitle("SetYourTitle Here") in your desired activity.