# Change the text colour of action bar title

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to change the text colour of the title in the action bar and from doing a little research I have come up with this.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle"   tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background"  tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/action_bar_blue</item>
        <item name="background">@color/action_bar_blue</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This does not change the text colour of the action bar title. What is the correct way to change the text colour?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom actionbar and make changes as per your need.

```
private void getCustomActionbar() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        int width = Constants.getScreenResolution(mContext);
        View mCustomView;       

        mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.secondcustom_actionbar, null);

        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }
```

call this method in oncreate.

or you can follow this link

[How to change the text on the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

**toolbar.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tool_head"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/new_account_toolbar_tittle"
                android:textColor="@color/white" 
                android:textSize="@dimen/heading_text" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/shadow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**In your activity**

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.base_color));
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            TextView userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tool_head);
            userName.setText(mTag);
           //Set text color here if you need to do programmatically
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this from java also, like this

```
myActionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0088'>MyTitle</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

you can change your theme like this.

```
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
     <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
     <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
   </style>
```

now the text color will change.