# How to add custom font to the action bar?

Tags: android, fonts, android-actionbar, android-appbarlayout

I wanted to know how to add my own custom font to the app name that appears in the action bar in android studio.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android?rq=1

Comment: OP did you tried anything ? If `yes` then post the code pls ~thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set CustomLayout in ActionBar

```
this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.titleview, null);

//if you need to customize anything else about the text, do it here.
//I'm using a custom TextView with a custom font in my layout xml so all I need to do is set title
((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(this.getTitle());

//assign the view to the actionbar
this.getActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

You can assign the custom font to textview by using `setTypeFace()`

Answer (score 0):

I did this by just making an image of the app name with the custom font then displaying the image as the logo in the action bar.  Much simpler.

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.app_logo);
```

Comment: But what about the size of the Image?

Comment: The image is scaled to fit the action bar quite nicely.  Oh, and the letters were different colors -- white and back against.a blue action bar.  Looked great.