# Android application with a long name in the Play Store, but a short name on Dashboard

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

Is it possible to give an Android application a long name to display in the Google Play Store, but display a short name on the dashboard & menu?

The name I want to give to my app is "Visioenen van Bosch", which is too long for the dashboard and the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The play store name is set during the publish process, and it has nothing to do with the actionBar's / Toolbar's title name, or name of the app's icon.

The values.xml file takes care of that :

```
    <string name="app_name">Visionen</string>
    <string name="title_activity_<insert activity name>">Visionen</string>
```

The first is the app icon / launchpad name, and the second, any of your custom acitivity names you want to set.

For more information on actionbar title:

[actionbar title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android)

[material toolbar tutorial](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-toolbar-tutorial-with-material-design/)

Comment: no problem, feel free to accept as valid if it's what you wanted to know :p

Comment: I will, after the minimum waiting period :)