# Android app always show app name in toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to show a specific text in my app toolbar but it also always shows the name of the app too. How can I get rid of the app name and only the text of the `TextView`?

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="The title I want to show"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: specify android:label="You Text" OR in activity class getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Text");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add label to activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
    <activity
        ....
        android:label="Name of Your Screen"
        ....
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 4):

For static activity name, set `android:label="Activity Name"` attribute for each `activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
...
<activity
    ...
    android:label="Activity Name">
    ...
</activity>
...
```

For dynamic activity name, you can use [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android):

```java
getActionBar().setTitle("Activity Name");
```

To provide compatibility across all the android versions, use:

```java
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Activity Name");
```

But if you want to completely get rid of the title bar, you can extend `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity` or you can hide the action bar:

```java
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Answer (score 4):

you just write this line in your activity `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

and it will set the visibility of the app name to invisible

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<activity 
    android:label="blah-blah" />
```

to set it in the manifest file.
Or in the code `toolbar.setTitle("blah-blah");`
If you set your `Toolbar` like `ActionBar` then you can call `actionBar.setTitle("blah-blah");`.

Answer (score 0):

From the modification of the accepted answer, this actually resolved my issue.

All you need to do is to leave the "label name"  text as blank in your manifest as example below

```
...
<activity
    ...
    android:label="  ">
    ...
</activity>
...
```

this will actually enable only your textview  text in your toolbar widget to show, it works very fine for me