# Change the App name to some other text in the top bar

Tags: android

Can please someone tell me how to change the App name in the top bar of my android App that gets displayed by default to some other text? I have seen this in a few Apps I used before. I'm building my first Android App and don't have that much experience with this stuff... thank you :)

Comment: In order for someone to answer you, you have to show what you researched, how you tried to implement and the issues you faced.

Comment: Check Solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/how-to-change-the-text-on-the-action-bar

Comment: @BogdanC sorry I didn't know that I had to be that specific :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is easier if you convert the actionbar (which I think is the bar you mean) into a toolbar if you want to do further modifications to it (as I assume):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);    
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

to change the title then simply call actionbar.setTitle as shown here:

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Your Title");
```

and if you want a subtitle add:

```
    actionBar.setSubtitle("Your Subtitle");
```

Comment: yes you need to put this in your onCreate method of your activity you want this to happen in

Answer (score 3):

after 
`setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);` 
simply add

```
setTitle("title_name");
```

this will change the name of your current activity in top bar or toolbar and i think your activity should extend AppCompactActivity

Comment: I did use the way the other guy told me so didn't try this one ;)

Comment: no worries. you may use it in another project or later ;)

Comment: It worked in Kotlin too - `MainActivity.kt` in function `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new support library, you should use this:

```
Toolbar toolber = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(Toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("App Title");
```