# how to change the text on the AppTheme?

Tags: android

I want to change the title that appear on my app. 
This text is taken from the string.xml => the 'app_name' 
Can't remove and use some other AppTheme ( using the default ) because this remove the 3 dots that i have to show the 'settings' activity.

I trying to play with all the AppTheme settings .. and nothing change this text.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the text on the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/how-to-change-the-text-on-the-action-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in Your `OnCreate()` method of Your Activity

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Prem");
```

OR

add `android:label="PREM"` in your `Activity` tag in manifest file like below code

```
<activity
     android:name=".YourAactivity"
     android:label="PREM" <--addhere your activity name--> />
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to `manifests` > `AndroidManifest.xml` > You can change the title by changing the `android:label` field, in this specific case find `aplication` and change `android:label`. If you want an specific activity, you find the activity and is the same process