# How can i change the text in the app bar?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am currently working on an app that requires the navigation template from creation. I have been fine-tuning the look of the default navigation template for the app I need to work on. However, there's one thing I have been unable to find a solution to which is to change the text in the app bar. It keeps saying 'Home' but I need to put the title of my app there. I have tried several things such as: `setTitle("App title here")` in the mainActivity, and in the manifest file I have also tried changing the text in `android:label` to the App title but nothing I do from the solutions I find online seems to work.

Is there any way I can get around this and change the 'home' text into my App's title? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**Code inside OnCreate as requested in a comment:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setTitle("Simple Dark Calculator")
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)



    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow), drawerLayout)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

Comment: Show us your code inside of `onCreate` so we can help you better.

Comment: @Armin updated my question.

Comment: Check this [out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63152963/13031115)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#top_app_bar):

> NavigationUI uses the destination labels from your navigation graph to keep the title of the top app bar up-to-date.

In your navigation graph change the **`android:label`** of the `startDestination`.

```
<navigation 
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        ... >

    </fragment>
```

You can also use the **`OnDestinationChangedListener`** to set the title after your setup method:

```
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
        if (destination.id == R.id.nav_xxx){
            supportActionBar?.title = "My Title"
        }
        //.....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `setTitle("Simple Dark Calculator")` line and add code below after `setSupportActionBar`  method:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Simple Dark Calculator");
```

To read more about setting up the app bar:
[Set up the app bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up#java)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Youractivityname"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```